# Internet Explorer 11 - Difficulties in Selecting Text

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, select, internet-explorer-10

I'm running my .NET application in Internet Explorer(Version 11) in compatibility mode. I'm using grid views to display content on my ASPX page. When I open the page and tried to select some cell or row from grid views, it is not selecting properly.
It is so difficult or impossible to select exactly the text you wanted to copy into an e-mail or a document. When you dragged the mouse to select text, you often selected adjacent paragraphs or columns also, even though you didn't want them.

**Working fine with Earlier edition(IE 10) and Firefox and Chrome. I have to fix/find out why It is not working in IE 11.**

Please let me know how to fix this one.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a "feature" in IE11 and there's no way to fix it in the code.  IE11 text selection seems to struggle once it hits any HTML structures (spans, divs).

There is a work around for users but it's a bit painful.  Press F7 to turn on caret mode, then you can select one item (double click) and then, holding down the shift key, use the cursor keys to highlight a selection.

If you have a lot of users, it would be better to implement an "Export to Excel" or "Copy to Clipboard" function than rely on text selections to get to the data.

Answer (score 0):

IE also allows for entire field selection using CTRL+Click (Left Mouse Click).
Edge, nor Chrome allows for this superior selection technique.